# "String data, right truncation" call BCP

Tags: sql-server, command-line, bcp

This is the BCP command I use for inserting data in SQL server:

```
bcp sfnav.dbo.Customer in "C:\Users\TSL\Desktop\TSL Data\ID_Customer_151124.csv" -F2 -c -t "^" -r "\n" -S ftpserver\sqlexpress -U abc -P xyz
```

When I try to run the same command in a batch file it results in an error:

```
call bcp sfnav.dbo.Customer in "C:\Users\TSL\Desktop\TSL Data\ID_Customer_151124.csv" -F2 -c -t "^" -r "\n" -S ftpserver\sqlexpress -U abc -P xyz
```

Error:

> Starting copy... SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0 Error =
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right
>   truncation SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0

Comment: Your row delimiter is likely incorrect and should probably be `\r\n`. Check your data file in a viewer that shows special characters. Eg in Notepad++, go to View>Show Symbol>Show All Characters and inspect the row delimiter.

Comment: Similar issue reported [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11566658/243373) on StackOverflow

Comment: If the row delimiter is really `\n`, try the hexadecimal value: `-r "0x0a"`

Comment: I tried to replace \n by "0x0a" but still it is showing same error. Normaly it works fine when I run the command seperately. But when I run in batch that is .bat file it results in Error

Comment: Did you check the actual delimiters in Notepad++ or a similar program clearly showing the row delimiter?

Comment: Well, like I said in my first comment, your delimiter should be `\r\n`.

Comment: then what should be the solution. User is sending me file with that format. How should I modify my command to execute?

Comment: Did I not just type out twice what I think your problem is? Ok for a third time, use the switch `-r \r\n` instead of `-r \n`.

Comment: Its working for me Thanks for the help

Comment: Try using Hexadecimal EOL character as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27793486/813739

Answer (score 1):

You want to check length of the receiving table columns. If it is shorter than the value from BCP for this column you will have fun having this error!!!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting RIGHT TRUNCATION error when I tried extracting an image file from Access
and inserting it as a blob into SQL Server database. I solved my problem by changing
the blob column data type from VARBINARY(MAX) to IMAGE on the target Sql server. If
this Image data type change works for you then just keep in mind that the max size
is 2 GB.