# "Impossible to execute Save action: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement" using OpenXava?

Tags: java, hibernate, mappedsuperclass, openxava

I am very new to Java and am in need of some help. I have created a @MappedSuperclass "Attendees" using OpenXava.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.*;
import org.openxava.annotations.*;

@MappedSuperclass
public class Attendees {
    
    @Id @Hidden @Column(length = 3)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid") @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy="uuid")
    private String oid;

    public String getOid() {
        return oid;
    }
    public void setOid(String oid) {
        this.oid = oid;
    }
}
```

I then extended it with two further classes "Staff" and "Participants".

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Staff extends Attendees{
    
    @Column (length = 50) 
    private String fullName;
    
    @Column (length = 2) 
    private int age;

    @Column (length = 10) 
    private int contactNum;
    
    @Embedded 
    private Address address; 

    @Embedded
    private MedicalInformation medicalInfo;


... 
}
```

and

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Participants extends Attendees{
    
    @Column (length = 50) 
    private String fullName;
    
    @Column (length = 2) 
    private int age;

    @Column (length = 10) 
    private int contactNum;
    
    @Embedded 
    private Address address; 

    @Embedded
    private MedicalInformation medicalInfo;

...
}
```

Below is the code for the two @Embedded elements:

Address:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Embeddable
public class Address {
    
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String street;
    
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String suburb;
 
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String city;
 
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String province;
    
    @Column(length = 5)
    private int areaCode;

...
}
```

and

MedicalInformation:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Embeddable
public class MedicalInformation {
    
    @Column (length = 3)
    private String dailyMedication;
    
    @Column (length = 300)
    private String medicationDescription;
    
    @Column (length = 300)
    private String allergies;
    
    @Column (length = 300)
    private String dietRequirements;
    
    @Column (length = 300)
    private String additionalNotes;

...
}
```

Apart from the Attendees class, I have omitted all getters() and setters().

I run the application as a Java Application and it works up until the point that I attempt to input and save a record. when I click "save" I am prompted with:

```
 Impossible to execute Save action: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
```

upon closer inspection in the consol of OpenXava I find the following:

```
Oct 25, 2020 5:03:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 3401, SQLState: 22001
Oct 25, 2020 5:03:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: data exception: string data, right truncation;  table: PARTICIPANTS column: OID
Oct 25, 2020 5:03:36 PM org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager manageRegularException
SEVERE: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1459)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1439)
    at org.openxava.jpa.impl.EntityManagerDecorator.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.model.impl.JPAPersistenceProvider.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.model.impl.MapFacadeBean.commitTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.model.impl.MapFacadeBean.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.model.MapFacade.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.actions.SaveAction.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.actions.SaveAction.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.executeAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.executeAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.xava.execute_jsp._jspService(execute_jsp.java:266)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516)
    at org.openxava.web.servlets.Servlets.getURIAsStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.getURIAsStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.request(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFilter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:431)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:283)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3174)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3688)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1453)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: string data, right truncation;  table: PARTICIPANTS column: OID
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:136)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 68 more
```

other Entities in the application that I have not mentioned here, allow me to save new records. these Entities are however not linked or related to the provided code.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
@Id @Hidden @Column(length = 3)
@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid") @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy="uuid")
private String oid;
```

By:

```
@Id @Hidden @Column(length = 32)
@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid") @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy="uuid")
private String oid;
```

Note @Column(length = 32) instead of @Column(length = 3). Also you have to drop your tables in order OpenXava generates them again, of if they already have data just do a ALTER TABLE to change the column length for OID column.

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear:

"SQLDataException: data exception: string data, right truncation;  table: PARTICIPANTS column: OID"

the problem is in the OID column in the table Participants (the string you are trying to insert is truncated for some reason) and it could be related to what said by jamie:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53182256/13745944